# How to create custom NHunspell dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, hunspell, nhunspell

I have made a C# windows application using NHunspell with its english dictionary.

What I need is another list of some English words to make my dictionary(not all English words). So if I delete all the words in the .dic text file and add my word list as following, will it work correctly?

```
NHunspell.Hunspell hunspell = new NHunspell.Hunspell(".affPath", ".dicPath");
String[] words = GetUserWords();
foreach (String word in words)
   hunspell.Add(word);
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Did you try something? What didn't work?

Comment: You code will add words from GetUserWords(); to the Hunspell object. But what do you meen with "dic test" ?